# Facebook redirection after login

Tags: facebook, authentication

I googled for nearly 4 hours and am posting this.
I am trying to implement facebook login in my website.
The problem is login is working fine, after login it has to redirect to anther custom page,
its not redirecting but staying in the same page. Here is my code that am using.

```
 <head>
       <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
       <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <fb:login-button perms="email"></fb:login-button>

    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId  : 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                status : true,
                cookie : true,
                xfbml  : true
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
                window.location = "about_us.html";
            });
        };

        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
    </script>

      <!-- <div class="fb-login-button" >Login with Facebook</div> -->
```

Kindly guide me where am wrong also if possible correct code
I had taken the code from below link.
[Redirect after clicking on the Facebook login button, even if already logged in Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835843/redirect-after-clicking-on-the-facebook-login-button-even-if-already-logged-in)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using this [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to determine the login state and perform your window.location redirection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just add this somewhere

```
FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
        window.top.location = "http://www.foo.com";
     }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I put

```
window.top.location = "http://www.foo.com";
```

under

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
statusChangeCallback(response);
window.top.location = "";
});
```

it worked.